# Low quality image on retina display

Tags: ios, uiimageview, png, retina-display

I have an UIImageView that I use to show a png file in an iPad game to identify the player faction. The png is 184x184, the UIImage view is 92x92. When I run the app in the simulator with retina display it clearly loses quality, but I don't get why. http://oi46.tinypic.com/2cg0n5k.jpg
I have many other images but no problems with them. What could it be?

Comment: Are you setting the `shouldRasterize` flag on the view's layer?

Comment: Mmm, what? If it is not of default I guess I am not, should I set it?

Answer (score 2):

When I do this I actually always have two files... Here's how I would do it:

1) Create PNG file that's 92x92 and name it image.png (for demonstration)

2) Create PNG file that's 184x184 and name it image@2x.png

Then when you plug them into the image view you can make it display "image.png" and it will pull image@2x on its own if it is indeed a retina display.

Comment: Tried, but I got the same result. The @2x image load correctly (I've tried putting a different image) but the quality is always the same (poor).

Comment: Is your DPI different for this image than ones you say work okay?

Comment: They are all 264 ppi. I have also tried saving the problematic one in 72 ppi too but it is the same.

Comment: Reducing the ppi would work against you in this case. To check if it is a problem with your image or your imageview, have you tried placing a second test imageview near it? That way you can add the image there too and see if the problem still exists. If the secondary imageview works as needed, you can ditch the original.

Comment: With a new UIImageView, setting the mode to “center”, the image quality is ok, like the original, but strangely it looks like if the pixels are doubled. So my 184x184 png actually occupies 368x368 pixels. Using mode different from “center” the quality still get low. Thhere must be something strange happening with the png.

Comment: I also noticed that whenever you set an imageView mode to "center" the quality sucks. But setting it to "top" or "bottom" the quality remains sharp. Must be a bug somewhere.